# Java application running with JNA works in IDE but not standalone

Tags: java, osgi, jna

we got a C# library that is used by our java code with JNA.

When we start it in the eclipse IDE it is working fine but when we extract it as a standalone application it does not work with the following error message:

```
java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeVoid(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:374)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:323)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:236)
at com.sun.jna.Native$3.invoke(Native.java:1040)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.init(Unknown Source)
at com.test.FooImpl.init(FooImpl.java:133)
```

the error occurs when we try to use a method from our lib written in C#.
While remote debuggig we found out that the instance, here CSharpWrapper, is not null and has a valid proxy to the dll.
Also it does not enter the C# code. It seems that it breaks between the JNA and the C#.

```
this.cSharpWrapper.init();
```

init is a void function in the C# lib.

What could be the cause here?

Comment: Make sure that the dll's the app depends on, are available in your classpath of the exported app.

Comment: thanks that was the problem! The C# dll dependencies were not available.